# How to update the status of a task that have sub task in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
+----+---------+--------+-----------+
| id | title   | status | parent_id |
+----+---------+--------+-----------+
|  1 | Task 1  |      2 |         0 |
|  2 | Task 2  |      2 |         3 |
|  3 | Task 3  |      0 |         0 |
|  4 | Task 4  |      2 |         3 |
|  5 | Task 5  |      0 |         3 |
|  6 | Task 6  |      2 |         5 |
|  7 | Task 10 |      2 |         0 |
|  8 | Task 8  |      0 |         0 |
+----+---------+--------+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

I have the above table structure. From the records it can be seen that `TASK 2`, `TASK 4` and `TASK 5` are the child of `TASK 3` and `TASK 5` again have  a child `TASK 6`.

The needed operations are:

1. Marking a task as DONE will also check the status of all sub task. When all
   sub task are COMPLETE, mark the task as COMPLETE (instead of DONE).
2. Marking a task as IN PROGRESS (**by changing the status to 0**) should update its
   parent task (if it has one) so that the parent’s status changes from COMPLETE to
   DONE. A parent task must not revert to IN PROGRESS from DONE or COMPLETE.

The status values for each state

1. **IN PROGRESS**
2. **DONE**
3. **COMPLETE**

Comment: so what you have tried yet??

Comment: and is it complete means 1 and done means 2 ?

Comment: The DONE status is specific to a single task by itself, while the COMPLETE status reflects the statuses
of all sub tasks. If a task is marked as DONE but has no sub task, it must be automatically
marked as COMPLETE instead. A task that’s being marked as DONE that does have sub task can
only be marked COMPLETE when all of its subtask are also COMPLETE.

Comment: "Marking a task as DONE will also check the status of all sub task." I don't really understand what this means.

Comment: @Strawberry  Marking a task as DONE(Status 2) will also change the status of all sub task to 2.

Comment: ...even if the subtask was previously described as 'complete'?

Comment: @Strawberry yes Marking a task as COMPLETE (by changing the status to 2) should update its parent task (if it has one) so that the parent’s status changes from IN PROGRESS to DONE.

Comment: I'm talking about the 'child' or 'subtask'

Comment: yes that case also same

Comment: Hm, I think this is pretty complicated.

Comment: @Strawberry i don't want to solve it in query level even a app level php script is enough.